# How to draw on Canvas by finger on top of a layout? (with text views and image views)

Tags: android, canvas, layout, draw

I'm building a project to help with calligraphy for kids.

I intend to place a letter on the screen and the user draws on top of the letter using the fingers/a smartphone pen.

I've managed to implement drawing on the screen, but I am having trouble joining it to the activity that gets the coordinates.

How can I do it? Since I can only setContentView() to one of them.

Comment: There are many finger-drawing libraries such as [this one](https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/DrawingView-Android), [this one](https://github.com/RiccardoMoro/FreeDrawView), and [this one](https://github.com/PaNaVTEC/DrawableView). Use one. Or, use them as a source of inspiration for your own version.

Comment: Hey, I got it! 
Using one of this libraries I've put a transparent activity on top of another view (with the letters) and it worked perfectly!

 Thank you!